# How to mock chained associations in rails and rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, rspec-rails

In my `SubscriptionsController` I have:

```
  # DELETE /subscription # {{{
  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.find params[:id]
    @subscription.cancel!
    redirect_to subscriptions_path, :notice => "Abonnement beendet." 
  end# }}}
```

What is the correct way to mock out `current_user.subscriptions.find params[:id]` in my Controller-Specs?

Currently I am trying this in my before block.

```
  double(Subscription)
  controller.current_user.stub!(:subscriptions).and_return(Subscription)
  Subscription.stub!(:find).and_return(subscription)
```

but this seems not to work as expected because my RSpec-Expectations don't work.

```
it "updates the status to canceled" do
  sub = Subscription.stub!(:find).and_return(subscription)
  sub.stub!(:cancel!)
  sub.should_receive :cancel!
  delete :destroy, :id => 1
end
```

this block always fails becaus the `should_receive` expectation is not met:

```
1) SubscriptionsController DELETE /subscription/:id updates the status to canceled
  Failure/Error: sub.should_receive :cancel!
    (#<Proc:0x007fbdec0a2650@/Users/nilsriedemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-perf@bloomy-days/gems/rspec-mocks-2.6.0/lib/rspec/mocks/message_expectation.rb:63 (lambda)>).cancel!(any args)
     expected: 1 time
     received: 0 times
     # ./spec/controllers/subscriptions_controller_spec.rb:38:in
     # `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # '
```

Besides if anyone drops nice links to thorough articles about stubbing, mocking in the comments, i'd be ridiculously happy. Still (obviously) not getting the hang of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `should_receive` on Subscription, not on the object that `find` will return.

Something like

```
Subscription.stub!(:find).and_return(subscription)
subscription.should_receive :cancel!
```

is what you are after.

You may also be interested in `stub_chain`:

```
some_user.stub_chain(:subscriptions, :find => some_result)
```

sets things up so that

```
some_user.subscriptions.find
```

returns `some_result`

Comment: That worked perfectly for me, so thanks! I also tried to stub several properties of the chain at once, but it didn't work. You have to declare a separate `#stub_chain` for each property. It's probably obvious to some, but it tripped me up for a while so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways to do it. If you want a simple solution, you can use stub_chain and pass it as many methods as you want:

```
let(:subscription) { mock(:subscription) }
current_user.stub_chain(:subscriptions, :find) { subscription }
```

And yet another would be to not use active record directly and have a finder method on the user model:

```
let(:subscription) { mock(:subscription) }
current_user.stub(:find_subscription) { subscription }
```

It's really a matter of opinion and comes down to whatever you feel most comfortable with. I personally would go with option one.